# How to display specific decimal places but still keep raw value in input Angular 10?

Tags: angular

I have some troubles.
The customers requests us with condition in input as

1. step 1: User want to display number with decimal 2 places
2. step 2: User are focusing in input => display full number
3. step 3: Out focusing in input => display such as step 1
4. step 4: User click on Save button. We still store data with full number

For ex:
User input 23.33324 => out focus, display on input is 23.3 => in focus => 23.33324 => save data into db => 23.33324

How to do that in angualr 10 (using formgroup)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Another approach in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875918/convert-a-number-to-currency-format-in-angular-10/72879151#72879151)

a FormControl exist even if there're no input, so you can use a [ngModel] (ngModelChange)

declare an empty array of booleans (*)

```
focus:boolean[]=[]
```

And use some like:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
  <input style="text-align:right"
  [ngModel]="focus[0]?myform.get('control').value:(+myform.get('control').value).toFixed(2)"
  (ngModelChange)="myform.get('control').setValue($event)"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
  (focus)="focus[0]=true" (blur)="focus[0]=false">
</form>
```

**Update** you can also "format the number" using the angular formatNumber function -the function that use pipe number-. Just create a function format

```
  import {formatNumber} from '@angular/common'
  format(number:number)
  {
    return formatNumber(number,'en-US','0.2-2')
  }
```

And replace the `[ngModel]` in the input by

```
[ngModel]="focus[1]?myform.get('control2').value:format(+myform.get('control2').value)"
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gwdu7j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

(*)I imagine you has severals "inputs", so for one of then use `focus[0]`, for another one `focus[1]`...

Comment: I'm using formControlName .  It alsway get latest value when focus or un-foucs

Comment: The "key" is **not** use `formControlName`, use a `[ngModel]` that change the value of a FormControl

Answer (score 1):

The reusable and best way would be to create your own custom FormControl, ie. a component which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

There are plenty of tutorials out there too.